# Windows Vista Home Premium -- Show Last Logged On User

Tags: windows, windows-vista

Is there a way in Windows Vista Home Premium to show the last logged on user's account at the log in screen instead of having to click on the user's icon (if there are multiple users)?

Answer (score -2):

Run Registry Editor (RegEdit).
Navigate to the following registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

In the right pane, double click on DontDisplayLastName registry key value, and set its value data to 1.

Alternatively, the registry key above can be changed and modified via Local Security Policy Editor, as shown in guide below.

Click on Start button, and type secpol.msc into Start Search box, and hit Enter to open the Local Security Policy Editor.
Navigate to Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options.
In the right pane, double click on Interactive Logon: Do not display last user name.
Select and set the radio button of Enabled.

Click Apply or OK.
Once enabled, the name of the last user to successfully log on is not displayed in the Logon Screen.